# Entity Framework query with grouping (many to many)

Tags: linq-to-sql, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a classical many to many scenario with three tables (students, courses, and third StudentsCourses assignment table).

I'm using EF in my new project and EF designer doesn't create third table.
I need to select all cources along with number of students assigned to it.
Using plain SQL is very straightforward:

```
select c.Id, c.Name, Count(sc.*) as StudentCount 
from Courses c left join StudentCourses sc on(c.Id=sc.CourseId)
group by c.Id, c.Name
```

But I can't figure out how to translate this query to Linq to SQL.
Please advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EF designer hides the table. It's still there, but it just creates the assocation for you, so you can just reference students from courses or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var list = from c in context.Courses
           from s in c.Students
           select new
           {
             StudentName=s.Name,
             Class=s.Class,
           };
```

for more information look at [this page](http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/many-to-many-relationships-in-the-entity-data-model/)